# how to access to textbox from async Task

Tags: c#, visual-studio, async-await, httpclient

how to access to `textbox` and fill by `responseString` received by http request?

```
    public async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        await RunAsync();
    }


    static async Task RunAsync()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "token", "aez" },
            };

            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

            var response = await client.PostAsync("localhost", content);

            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use string from result of `Task<string>`.

```
public async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textbox.Text = await RunAsync();
}

static async Task<string> RunAsync() 
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "token", "aez" },
        };

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

        var response = await client.PostAsync("localhost", content);

        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

Or you can make `RunAsync` non static, so you can access textbox with `this` reference. just remove static keyword and assign value to textbox within method.

```
async Task RunAsync()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "token", "aez" },
        };

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

        var response = await client.PostAsync("localhost", content);

        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        textbox.Text = responseString;
    }
}
```